# Extracting a table by webscraping using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, pagination

Using BeautifulSoup in python I'm trying to extract this [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CD6U.png).

First I have to put the "From date" and "To date" to collect the desired data within that duration. The links which I have found from inspecting the Html page are as below.

```
<ul class="pager"><li class="pager-current first">1</li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 2" href="/shop/finance-manager/mprequest?page=1&amp;shop%2Ffinance-manager%2Fmprequest=">2</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 3" href="/shop/finance-manager/mprequest?page=2&amp;shop%2Ffinance-manager%2Fmprequest=">3</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 4" href="/shop/finance-manager/mprequest?page=3&amp;shop%2Ffinance-manager%2Fmprequest=">4</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 5" href="/shop/finance-manager/mprequest?page=4&amp;shop%2Ffinance-manager%2Fmprequest=">5</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 6" href="/shop/finance-manager/mprequest?page=5&amp;shop%2Ffinance-manager%2Fmprequest=">6</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 7" href="/shop/finance-manager/mprequest?page=6&amp;shop%2Ffinance-manager%2Fmprequest=">7</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 8" href="/shop/finance-manager/mprequest?page=7&amp;shop%2Ffinance-manager%2Fmprequest=">8</a></li>
<li class="pager-item"><a title="Go to page 9" href="/shop/finance-manager/mprequest?page=8&amp;shop%2Ffinance-manager%2Fmprequest=">9</a></li>
<li class="pager-ellipsis">…</li>
<li class="pager-next"><a title="Go to next page" href="/shop/finance-manager/mprequest?page=1&amp;shop%2Ffinance-manager%2Fmprequest=">next ›</a></li>
<li class="pager-last last"><a title="Go to last page" href="/shop/finance-manager/mprequest?page=11&amp;shop%2Ffinance-manager%2Fmprequest=">last »</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here links are all coming under 'pager-item' but the actual number of the page can be seen from the "pager-last last" section (which is 11). So i have to run a code which is for all this 11 pages (using a forloop may be).

This is the [html portion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXmJn.png) from where I intend to **scrape**.

Here is my code for a single page **scrape** which is running fine.

```
Beautiful_Fin_Page = bs(Total_Fin_Page.content, 'lxml')
OrderID_Container = Beautiful_Fin_Page('tbody')

Table = {
           "Transaction Number": [],
           "Sale Order": [],
           "Return Sale Order": [],
           "Requisition Date": [],
           "Requisition Time": []
           }
           
    for orders in OrderID_Container:
     if orders.find('tr') is not None:
         trs = orders.find_all('tr',{'class': ['odd', 'even']})
         for tr in trs:
             td = tr.find_all('td')
             print(td)
             
             Table["Transaction Number"].append(td[0].text)
             Table["Requisition Date"].append(td[3].text)
             Table["Requisition Time"].append(td[4].text)
             Table["Customer Name"].append(td[5].text)
             
df = pd.DataFrame(Table)
print(df)
```

So can you please share how can I extract the total table data using a "forloop" for pagination purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Im going to assume you have some base url that you are scraping from:

the for loop you need is

```
for i in range(12):
    url=f"{baseurl}/shop/finance-manager/mprequest?page={i}&amp;shop%2Ffinance-manager%2Fmprequest="
    your_function_to_extract_the_data_you_need(url)
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. But the fact is what will be the value in "range" you never know. as the no of pages which is generated totally depends on the date range that I'm selecting first. it's totally a variable. I have to make a variable where it will take the no of loop from this "pager-next" or "pager-last last" class if anyone of them is available

Comment: @OmarHasib then try to select the element based on css selector. cant remember the syntax now but the selector shuld be `li.pager-last.last` then get the href of that and extract the number with this regex: `(?<=page=).*(?=&)`